# Airflow DAG successfully executed but tasks didn't run

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a DAG in airflow with one task (a python operator) which I force to run in the GUI and it gets the successful state. However, the task is not executed and hence the DAG makes nothing. The code of the dag is the following:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.hooks import MySqlHook
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import json
from datetime import timedelta

default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'start_date': dt.datetime(2019,8,29,18,0,0),
        'concurrency':1,
        'retries':3
        }

def extraction_from_raw_data(conn_id):
    mysqlserver = MySqlHook(conn_id)
    query = """select * from antifraud.email_fraud_risk
            WHERE ts >= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -3 DAY)"""
    raw_data = mysqlserver.get_records(query)
    raw_data = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)

    data_as_list = []

    for i in range(len(raw_data)):
        dict1 = {}
        dict1.update(json.loads(raw_data.at[i,'raw_content']))
        data_as_list.append(dict1)

    json_data_df = pd.DataFrame(data_as_list)

    final_data = pd.concat([raw_data['email_id'],json_data_df],axis=1)

    return final_data

with DAG('emailage_data',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval = timedelta(days=1)
         ) as dag:
    extraction_from_raw_data = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'extraction_from_raw_data',
    op_args = {'conn_id':'services'},
    python_callable = extraction_from_raw_data)

extraction_from_raw_data
```

All worker, scheduler and webserver are working correctly because I am running a hello_world DAG (and its consequent tasks) with success.

Comment: Try changing your start date to a day earlier.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Thank you very much. You can post an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you should always leave an extra interval between your DAG's start time and the current time.

The Airflow documentation states that

> Note that if you run a DAG on a `schedule_interval` of one day, the run stamped `2016-01-01` will be trigger soon after `2016-01-01T23:59`. In other words, the job instance is started once the period it covers has ended.
>
> Let’s Repeat That The scheduler runs your job one `schedule_interval` AFTER the start date, at the END of the period.

https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html